# php - facebook app url doesn't 'change' when using app

Tags: php, facebook, url

When i'm using my Facebook app in an iframe and I, for example, click on a link that goes to `http://sub.mysite.com/edit.php`, it continues to show `http://apps.facebook.com/myapp` in the browser address bar instead of `http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/edit.php`.

So my question is: How do I display the bit after `http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/` if I click on edit.php or list.php in the browser address bar. `(http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/edit.php, http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/list.php)`

I know that this is possible as i've seen this in many facebook apps.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in HTML

```
<a href="http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/edit.php" target="_top" />
```